# Cannot send Two Strings Simultaneously in Bluetooth chat Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I have Modified the Bluetooth chat Application to Send Two Strings At Same time ( Transaction Number & Password ) ,Problem is when i press the Send button Only one string (Password) will be sending , i Dont know how to pass two strings Simulataneously.. [This is my Application Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Xhj.png)

Main Activity

```
private EditText et_tnum;
private EditText et_pass;
private TextView status;
private Button btnConnect;
private ListView listView;
private Dialog dialog;
private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> chatAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> chatMessages;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT = "device_name";

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
private ChatController chatController;
private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewsByIds();

    //check device support bluetooth or not
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    //show bluetooth devices dialog when click connect button
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPrinterPickDialog();
        }
    });

    //set chat adapter
    chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    chatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatMessages);
    listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setStatus("Connected to: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                        btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        setStatus("Connecting...");
                        btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case ChatController.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case ChatController.STATE_NONE:
                        setStatus("Not connected");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                chatMessages.add("Me: " + writeMessage);
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                chatMessages.add(connectingDevice.getName() + ":  " + readMessage);
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);
    dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");

    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    //Initializing bluetooth adapters
    ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    //locate listviews and attatch the adapters
    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
    ListView listView2 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
    listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
    listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        pairedDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_paired));
    }

    //Handling listview item click event
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

private void setStatus(String s) {
    status.setText(s);
}

private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
    chatController.connect(device);
}

private void findViewsByIds() {
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    et_tnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_tnum);
    et_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass);
    View btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (et_tnum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //TODO: here
                sendMessage(et_tnum.getText().toString());
                et_tnum.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (et_pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //TODO: here
                sendMessage(et_pass.getText().toString());
                et_pass.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth still disabled, turn off application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (chatController.getState() != ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection was lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (message.length() > 0) {
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        chatController.write(send);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
    } else {
        chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (chatController != null) {
        if (chatController.getState() == ChatController.STATE_NONE) {
            chatController.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatController != null)
        chatController.stop();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_found));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

Activity_layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not Connected" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Connect" />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="164dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_tnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Transaction Number"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="213dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append your password and mobile number in one string then send it over BT.

Comment: Here im using two different Edit text ,So i dont get any idea how to append.im newbie.pls See my Application Model.. help me

Comment: String passwordNMobile=password+","+mobileNumber;

on the other side, String [] params=String.split(passwordNMobile, ",");

now params[0] contains password and params[1] contains mobile number

Comment: btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


String number =et_tnum.gettext.toString();
String password=et_pass.getText().toString();
            if (et_pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //TODO: here
String numberpass=password+","+number;
                sendMessage(numberpass);
                et_pass.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}